# Is the subject-verb inversion in this sentence correct?

Tags: subject-auxiliary-inversion, negative-inversion

> She does not always mean good, and not always **is she** overt as to her real meaning.

I think "is" should come before "she" because of "not always". Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. It's the negative phrase "not always" that triggers the inversion. I don't think this construction adds much to the style. SF gives a couple of suitable alternatives in their answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, if a little fancy/antiquated. Normally, in most common form this sentence would go:

> She does not always mean good, and **she is** not always overt as to her real meaning.

Following a negating conjunction like that requires such inversion. Your case is unique in that the negating conjunction is spread between three words, `and not always` and the spirit of this rule ceases to be as apparent, but take this:

> She does not always mean good, **nor is she** overt as to her real meaning.

In this case the need for the reversal is obvious.